# Oracle row-level trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have some bugs about trigger...

I have looked through the document but did not find any solution.

The trigger is simple as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upm AFTER INSERT ON transaction
BEGIN
    UPDATE manufacturer M SET M.mPhoneNumber = M.mPhoneNumber+1 WHERE 
    M.mID = 
    (SELECT P.mID
     FROM part P where p.pID = :NEW.pID);
 END;
 /
```

This looks good.. But always end up in error.

```
2/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/3      PL/SQL: ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command
6/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following....
```

What's wrong?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Transaction is a reserved word,and you are using NEW for a table in which the INSERT doesn't happen.

Comment: but transaction is the name of my table...

Comment: And doesn't NEW refer to the new record you insert into the table transaction?

Comment: You can refer `:NEW` and `:OLD` only in a **row-level trigger** i.e. using `FOE EACH ROW` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a **statement-level trigger**. You could refer to the `:NEW` and `:OLD` values only with a **row-level trigger**.

From [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374),

> **FOR EACH ROW**
>
> Creates the trigger as a row trigger. The database fires a row trigger
>   for each row that is affected by the triggering statement and meets
>   the optional trigger constraint defined in the WHEN condition.
>
> If you omit this clause, then the trigger is a statement trigger. The
>   database fires a statement trigger only when the triggering statement
>   is issued if the optional trigger constraint is met.

You must use **FOR EACH ROW** clause to make it row-level trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upm 
AFTER INSERT ON transaction

-- add the below clause to make it row-level

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE manufacturer M SET M.mPhoneNumber = M.mPhoneNumber+1 WHERE 
    M.mID = 
    (SELECT P.mID
     FROM part P where p.pID = :NEW.pID);
 END;
 /
```

---

**UPDATE**

OP found the error due to the inconsistency of the file format while moving from Windows to Unix OS.

To fix the file format issue, do this:

```
dos2unix filename
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually originally I have that "FOR EACH ROW" ... But at that time it doesn't work. Just now I find out that it is because I'm copying statement from Windows to Unix through SSH... And new line character is different between systems. which causes the error.

Comment: @Tipton Thanks for the feedback. I added an update to the answer, you could do `dos2unix` to fix the file format in future.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Actually originally I have that "FOR EACH ROW" ... But at that time it doesn't work. Just now I find out that it is because I'm copying statement from Windows to Unix through SSH... And new line character is different between systems. which causes the error.